# How to add a directory to linker command line in linux

Tags: command-line, dynamic-linking

I am new to Linux and I want to add `lib64/librt.so.1` to the linker command line. Can anyone suggest how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

1. If you are compiling something and you want the compiler to search a specific directory, you can add the -L flag. Like this:

   ```
   g++ -L /lib64
   ```
2. You can also add this directory to the environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'. Like this:

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib64"
   ```
3. You can also use `ldconfig` to add a directory to the search path. Like this:

   ```
   sudo ldconfig /lib64
   ```
4. Finally, you can add the directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/mylibs.conf` (and rerun `sudo ldconfig`) to make this change permanent.

   ```
   echo "/lib64" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mylibs.conf; sudo ldconfig
   ```

Comment: For 4, probably better to add a `.conf` file to the /etc/ld.so.conf.d directory